# Angular 9 - Setting manually an error on a reactive form control won't change the form status

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm facing a certain scenario with Angular reactive forms that I have been unable to solve. I'm manually setting an error on a form control and I would expect this to change the form status to be invalid, but it doesn't. I have tried executing markAsTouched() and updateValueAndValidty() methods without success. I ignore if this is how Angular reactive forms are supposed to work or if there is something wrong with my code.

This is the architecture so far:

Parent component creates a form group.
Child component receives thay form group as an input property.
In the child component's template I use a third party component to render dynamically a collection of form fields. Sadly, I can't bind my form group directly to the third party component, but I do know when the third party form is valid or not. I'm trying to use this information to manually update my form group status.

**Parent component controller**

```
  export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.form = this.fb.group({
        firstControl: [],
        secondControl: [],
    });
}
```

}

**Parent component template**

```
<app-child-component
  [formGroup]="form">
</app-child-component>
```

**Child component controller**

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('thirdPartyForm') thirdPartyForm: NgForm;

  private thirdPartyFormStatusChangeSubscription$: Subscription;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.thirdPartyFormStatusChangeSubscription$ = this.thirdPartyForm.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
      this.onStatusChanges(status);
    });
  }

  private onStatusChanges(status: string){
    if (status === 'INVALID') {
        this.thirdPartyForm.controls.firstControl.setErrors({'invalid': true})
        console.log(this.thirdPartyForm.valid); // true despite the error!
    }
}
```

**Child component template**

```
<form #thirdPartyForm="ngForm">
  <app-third-party-form-wrapper
    [form]="thirdPartyForm" 
    [formFields]="formFields">
  </app-third-party-form-wrapper>
</form>
```

In the child component's controller, onStatusChanges method is correctly executed every time the form status changes. setErrors method is correctly invoked when the status is not valid too. However, the form status is never invalid despite the error. As stated above, I tried using a combination of methods hoping to refresh the status, but I never succeed:

```
this.form.controls.firstControl.setErrors({invalid: true});
this.form.markAsTouched();
console.log(this.form.valid) // still true!
this.form.updateValueAndValidity()
console.log(this.form.valid) // still true!
```

In a nutshell: Should the form status change when manually setting an error on a form's control? If yes, what it's wrong with my code?